# AJAX call caching via Promise makes browser use CPU (and leak memory)

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, promise

**UPDATE**: problem has mysteriously disappeared after a long jslint session, so I have to conclude that it was some silly error somewhere in my code, that got fixed by removing some apparently harmless typo.

## Initial problem

I have a page that loads a significant (and randomly variable) number of AJAX objects via jQuery `.post` calls.

So I'd be generating a lot of calls such as

```
/entry/get/orange
/entry/get/red
/entry/get/yellow
/entry/get/red      <--- duplicate!
/entry/get/red      <--- again!
/entry/get/yellow
/entry/get/red      <--- dude, what's wrong with you?
...
```

When running in this way, everything works as it should, apart from it being really, really inefficient, and hitting the server pretty needlessly.

## Solution attempt

So I switched to caching via Promise, like this:

```
// I have a global colorCache variable

function retrieve(color, callback) {
    console.log("retrieving " + color);
    var found = -1;
    // Each entry in colorCache is an object with some other values
    for (var i in colorCache) {
        if (colorCache[i].color === color) {
             found = i;
             break;
        }
    }
    if (found < 0) {
        console.log("effecting call for " + color);
        var url  = "blah/blah/blah/" + color;
        var ppar = {
            foo: "bar",
            answer: 42
        };
        /* push returns the new length of colorCache */
        found = colorCache.push({ 
            color   : color,
            promise : $.post(url, ppar),
            ts      : new Date().getTime()
        }) - 1;
    } else {
        console.log("cache hit for " + color);
    }
    // now found is valid. Return the Promise too, for appending.
    return colorCache[found].success(callback);
}
```

This way, if the relevant `.post` has been already issued, the callback is called again with the same data, whether the call itself has already terminated or is still in progress.

Again, everything works. **Apparently**.

## Now I have *another* problem

With this new version,

- the page loads
- all objects are loaded (way faster than before - as expected)
- the page stops, everything is still... no animations, no clocks, nothing...
- ...but Process Explorer now shows **Firefox constantly eating 26-30% of the CPU**. And it will *continue* to do so until and unless I close the tab where the page is loaded. Also, **Firefox memory consumption goes steadily up**. I've watched it rise from 800M to 1.7GB over a little less than an hour, not completely regularly, but with a distinct upward trend.

What could be the issue here?

**Important note**: there are several "browser leak" questions and answers on Stack Overflow, but they all involve *repeated* jQuery calls that allocate objects or iterate in some way. Here, once I've run some fifty jQuery calls, there's nothing else going on.

## What I have tried (so far)

- I've checked with Firebug: there are no console warnings or errors, no telltale logs (all functions I call have one), no network activity (double-checked from the Apache logs server side).
- I've looked at the Firefox process in memory; the main thread is running, but I'm no good at interpreting Process Explorer's thread information - it shows something about a "forInIterator" thing that tells me little.
- no activity except CPU appears to be afoot (network, Windows registry read/writes).
- I've googled a good bit, and found [something](https://github.com/cujojs/when/issues/43) possibly related (but possibly not). **I've not yet tried this suggestion**, but I will do it shortly even if I don't see how it can help, and anyway I don't use `when.js` even if something similar *might* have creeped in jQuery since: *One potential workaround is to ensure
  that your promise callbacks and errbacks return something (other than
  the $.Deferred).*
- wrapped the .post call with a Promise.resolve as suggested by Jaromanda X, and moved the cache object inside the function to avoid polluting the global scope (which is always a good practice).
- Returned directly the Promise object, and called the callback by appending an external .then.
- Tested with Chrome. Same results (in some ways it's reassuring), except CPU load is constant at 17%.
- Closing the tab makes CPU load go away.

Comment: Don't you need it to be: `return colorCache[found].promise.then(callback);`?  `colorCache[found]` is your object which does not have the `.success()` method you were trying to call.  Also, I switched to `.then()` to be much more future compatible since `.success()` is non-standard.

Comment: I've read the *jQuery.deferred* is not quite Promise/A+ spec - that doesn't mean that's the source of this issue, however, try "wrapping" the `$.post(url, ppar)` in native `Promise.resolve($.post(url, ppar))` and see if the cpu usage issue goes away - also, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qr4rx65/) of your retrieve function that doesn't need a global variable, and simplifies (I think) the logic (no for loops for finding cached values for example) - the fiddle wraps the jQuery as mentioned in this comment

Comment: @JaromandaX , I've tried, but did not work. I'll now try to reduce the number of calls and see if that shakes loose some clue.

Comment: "I have a page that loads a significant (and randomly variable) number of AJAX objects via jQuery .post calls." - it might be a good idea to reconsider your architecture - no fix we'll give you will help - that's an architectural issue.

Comment: Would using a not-lame promise library or request library be an option?

Comment: Yes, I'm considering sending a single, more complex object to the page, but that heavily hits responsivity. If there are no other alternatives I'll have to go with that, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** The problem is not *directly* related to caching at all. Caching, or rather: the higher call turnaround allowed by caching, appears to trigger a misunderstanding somewhere else in the jQuery/bootstrapSwitch relations. It's also possible that I'm using bootstrapSwitch incorrectly.

---

## Debugging and discovery

Since there are no XHR requests running, the CPU problem must be caused by either code looping explicitly, or doing so implicitly (e.g. setInterval).

Instrumenting the browser timer functions

```
window.timers = {}; 
originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
originalSetInterval = window.setInterval;
window.setTimeout = function(fu, t) {
    var id = originalSetTimeout(function() {
        console.log(id+" has timed out");
        delete window.timers[id]; // do not track popped timers 
        fu();
    }, t);
    window.timers[id] = {id:id, type: 'timeout', setAt: new Date(),  timeout: t };
    console.log(id+" has been set to pop in "+t+"ms");
}

window.setInterval = function(fu, t) {
    var id = originalSetInterval(function() {
        window.timers[id].fired++;
        fu();
    }, t);
    window.timers[id] = {id:id, type: 'interval', setAt: new Date(),  timeout: t, fired: 0 };
    console.log(id+" has been set to pop every "+t+"ms");
}
```

shows that **there are several timers running continuously**.

## Investigating the timers

The code is 'strict', but once the specific timer is known, I can throw an Exception inside my setInterval, and be able to inspect the call stack.

So it turns out that the culprit is this code (removing it makes the problem disappear):

```
    .bootstrapSwitch({
        onSwitchChange: function(e, state) {
            ...
        }
    })
```

## Conclusion

The cause of the problem is that I have quite a lot of checkboxes in the resulting page: they are beautified with bootstrapSwitch, but they start off as *hidden*. And in this case, bootstrapSwitch starts a timer that waits for the checkbox to be rendered before enriching its DOM. Apparently this is (one of?) the functions doing this:

```
 return initInterval = window.setInterval((function(_this) {
      return function() {
        if (_this.$wrapper.is(":visible")) {
          init();
          return window.clearInterval(initInterval);
        }
      };
    })(this), 50);
```

Normally these functions do not load the CPU significantly. But for unclear reasons, a large (40+) number of AJAX requests in a short time, some of which call bootstrapSwitch, make the above timers generate a much higher load.

Forcing the checkbox switches to show one after another, hiding them immediately after, also somewhat works: two timers remain, with a CPU load below 5%, but all the others correctly terminate. Checkbox flashing is awkward, though.

Finally, I have written a single timer function that will delay bootstrapSwitch until the relevant checkboxes *are* indeed visible. Once they are, bootstrapSwitch is invoked, but as they are visible, no additional timer is created. This way, whatever happens in the bowels of the timers code never gets triggered.